# B1/B2 visa for conference and tourism

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, conferences

I am an Indian citizen working in Germany at the moment and I hold a German residence permit. I applied for the US tourist visa in 2017 which was rejected for not having sufficient ties with Germany. I am applying for the visa again to attend a conference in UC Berkeley and since my last application was refused, I am being cautious. I have a few questions wrt the application.

> 1) Address Where You Will Stay in the U.S.

Which address should I give in this section as I will be in the conference for 3 days and then visit my sister who lives in Boston for 10 days. However, the primary purpose of the visit is to attend the conference.

> 2) Person/Entity Paying for Your Trip

My employer will be sponsoring the conference and everything (first 3 days) and I will pay for the rest of my stay. Shall I just select "Self" in this section as I don't have any problem in showing the funds?

> 3) Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five
>   years?

As I live in Germany, do I mention the countries I visited in the Schengen region as well?